# Problemas de conversão de campos tipo float

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou com um problema que a princípio, é bobo, porém não estou conseguindo resolver, eu tenho esta função em `ajax`, que pega os valores do `input`, e envia para o `controler`:

```
 var url = "/PedidoFornecedor/Adicionar1";
        var ProdutoPedidoID = $idprodutopedido;
        var ProdutoID = $("#produtoid").val();
        var CodigoProduto = $("#idproduto").val();
        var Qtd = $("#qtd").val();
        var QtdFalta = $("#qtd").val();
        var PrecoCusto = $("#precocusto").val();
        var DescontoV = $("#descontov").val();
        var DescontoP = $("#descontop").val();
        var ICMS = $("#icms").val();
        var AliquotaICMS = $("#aliquotaicms").html().replace("%", "");
        var IPI = $("#ipi").val();
        var ISS = $("#iss").val();
        var PedidoID = $("#pedidoid").val();
        var DataEntrega = $("#dataentrega").val();
        var DescricaoProduto = $("#descricaoproduto").html();
        var Total = (parseFloat(Qtd) * parseFloat(PrecoCusto.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) - parseFloat(DescontoV.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
        var vICMS = (parseFloat(Total) * (parseFloat(AliquotaICMS.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100));
        var vISS = (parseFloat(Total) * (parseFloat(ISS.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100));
        var vIPI = (parseFloat(Total) * (parseFloat(IPI.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100));

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {
                produtoPedidoID: ProdutoPedidoID, produtoID: ProdutoID, codigoProduto: CodigoProduto, qtd: Qtd, qtdFalta: QtdFalta, precoCusto: PrecoCusto,
                descontoV: DescontoV, descontoP: DescontoP, icms: ICMS, aliquotaICMS: AliquotaICMS,
                ipi: IPI, iss: ISS, dataEntrega: DataEntrega, pedidoID: PedidoID, descricaoProduto: DescricaoProduto,
                total: Total, vicms: vICMS, viss: vISS, vipi: vIPI
            },
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
```

E aqui é o código para receber no `controller`:

```
public ActionResult Adicionar1(int? produtoPedidoID, int produtoID, string codigoProduto, int qtd, int qtdFalta, float precoCusto, float descontoP,
     float descontoV, int icms, float aliquotaICMS, float ipi, float iss, DateTime? dataEntrega,
     int pedidoID, string descricaoProduto, float total, float vicms, float viss, float vipi)
    {
```

Nessas variáveis, porém nunca dá certo, toda vez que tento dá problema em algum número, se eu envio 1000,50 ele salva 100050, ou se eu envio 5.202,00 ele recebe sem estar formato, sempre com problemas em algum dos tipos. ou da problema nos centavos, ou nas dezenas, já tentei de várias maneiras, ou funciona um ou funciona do outro tipo, nenhuma forma que tentei funcionou 100%. 
Eu sei que é algo bobo, gostaria de entender melhor o que está acontecendo, nesses problemas de conversões. Já tentei também no controller receber do tipo string, e também sempre dá algum problema.

**EXEMPLO**
Dessa forma, no `debugger` o valor total que está sendo enviado por `ajax` é `5300.2`, e no `controller` ele está recebendo `53002` e o certo seria receber `5300,20`

**EDIT**
Tentei dessa forma abaixo e também não deu certo:

```
var Total = Number(parseFloat(Qtd) * Number(parseFloat(PrecoCusto.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')))) - Number(parseFloat(DescontoV.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')));
        var vICMS = Number(parseFloat(Total) * Number(parseFloat(AliquotaICMS.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100));
        var vISS = Number(parseFloat(Total) * Number(parseFloat(ISS.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100));
        var vIPI = Number(parseFloat(Total) * Number(parseFloat(IPI.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100));
```

Comment: Você está usando a vírgula para separar a parte inteira da fracionada? Verifique quem é o ponto decimal nas duas linguagens que você está trabalhando, o Javascript geralmente ignora a informação de localização e usa o "." (ponto) mas não sei se na linguagem do _controller_ (C#?) está igual.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o maskMoney?  Fizemos uma implementação bem parecida com essa sua, utilizamos o maskMoney para problemas de decimal.

Comment: @AdrianoPraia nunca utilizei, tem algum exemplo para auxiliar ?

Comment: Aqui no repositório tem exemplo de como usar o maskMoney, qualquer dúvida a disposição.

https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

Answer (score 0):

Use a função [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para formatar um número usando notação de ponto fixo.

## Exemplo:

```
console.log(Number.parseFloat("12.872").toFixed(2));
// retorna 12.87
```

---

## Voltando ao seu código:

```
//    Vou usar Total, PrecoCusto, DescontoV e Qtd numéricos para simplificar os calculos 
// e a leitura. Então vou cria os campos _Total, _PrecoCusto, _DescontoV e _Qtd
// pois não sei se você fará uso futuro dos valores originais.     
var _PrecoCusto = parseFloat( PrecoCusto.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.') );
var _DescontoV  = parseFloat( DescontoV.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.') );
var _Qtd = parseFloat( Qtd.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.') );
var _AliquotaICMS = parseFloat(AliquotaICMS.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100;
var _ISS = parseFloat(ISS.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100;
var _IPI = parseFloat(IPI.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) / 100;

Total = _Qtd *  _PrecoCusto - _Desconto;
var vICMS = Total * _AliquotaICMS ;
var vISS = Total * _ISS;
var vIPI = Total * _IPI;

//Lá em cima poderia ser feito var Total = (_Qtd *  _PrecoCusto - _Desconto).toFixed(2);
//Mas está dessa forma para simplificar a leitura. O mesmo vale para vICMS, vISS e vIPI 
Total = Total.toFixed(2);
vICMS = vICMS.toFixed(2);
vISS = vISS.toFixed(2);
vIPI = vIPI.toFixed(2);
```